# How to resize icons to smaller size on the desktop Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: nautilus, 16.10

My laptop's screen resolution is 1280x720 and even the smallest icon size in new version of Nautilus (3.20) is big for me. Is there any way to make it more smaller

Comment: Not without altering the source code & rebuilding nautilus. (and even that may create some  unintended  consequences).  Why do you want to use 16.10 anyway??